# In android, how do you modify this code to populate two textviews instead of one?

Tags: android

I am trying to modify the sample code below. It currently populates a View that contains an imageview and a textview. I have added an additional textview to my XML layout and am trying to figure out how to replace the simple array with a hash map or even a multidimensional array to populate not just the imageview and the first textview but also the second one.

I would appreciate sample code that shows the entire process. Thanks!

```
public class DynamicDemo extends ListActivity { 
  TextView selection; 
  private static final String[] items={"lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", 
          "sit", "amet"}
  @Override 
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter()); 
    selection=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selection); 
  } 

  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, 
                             int position, long id) { 
   selection.setText(items[position]); 
  } 

  class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> { 
    IconicAdapter() { 
      super(DynamicDemo.this, R.layout.row, R.id.label, items); 
    } 

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
                       ViewGroup parent) { 
      View row=super.getView(position, convertView, parent); 
      ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon); 

      if (items[position].length()>4) { 
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete); 
      } 
      else { 
        icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok); 
      } 

      return(row); 
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your xml file too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use an `ArrayAdapter<MyDataObject>` where

```
 public class MyDataObject {
      public String string1;
      public String string2;
      // any other useful attributes

 }
```

And then you would change `items` to a `MyDataObject[] items` stored in your class, and instead of doing `super.getView(index)` you'd do `items[index]` (which would yield a `MyDataObject`) and use that data instead.

Also, importantly:  you should [use the convertView](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html).  And possibly the [ViewHolder pattern](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/viewholder-pattern-caching-view-efficiently/).

**Edit**:  At OP's request, a little more elaboration.  Note that this uses the convertView pattern but not the ViewHolder pattern (you should be able to adopt that fairly easily).

In your `Adapter`, you'd change `getView()` as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, 
                   ViewGroup parent) { 

  ViewGroup row;
  if(convertView == null){
      // create your view here.
      row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row);   
  } else {
      row = convertView;
  }

  // note:  when you implement ViewHolder, the ViewHolder will
  // hold this reference so that you don't need to look it up every time.
  ImageView icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon); 

  // here you're employing the "items" array that you were using 
  // before, except now it contains MyDataObjects.  pick out the 
  // string (or other data you want to check) from the resulting MyDataObject, 
  // and see if it's longer than 4 characters.

  MyDataObject objectAtThisPosition = items[position];

  if (objectAtThisPosition.string1.length()>4) { 
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete); 
  } 
  else { 
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok); 
  } 

  // Do whatever else you want to with objectAtThisPosition.

  return(row); 
}
```

That's it for the easy way, and quite similar to what you have.

Some more detail; if you don't care, skip it.  :)

I know that Adapters can seem magical, so in the interest of showing how `ListView` adapters work, here's an example using a `List` instead of an `Array`, so we can remove any magic that `ArrayAdapter` does with the array behind the scenes.  I use a `List` because they can be more versatile for whatever you're trying to accomplish (`ArrayList` or `LinkedList` or what-have-you).

To use a `List` you'd have the following in your `Activity`:

```
 private List<MyDataObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyDataObject>();
```

And instead of `items[position]` you'd use

```
 MyDataObject objectAtThisPosition = myList.get(position);
```

If you want to change your data set dynamically, you should probably use this approach (keeping `myList` at the `Activity` level) instead of using an Array and an ArrayAdapter.  That would mean you'd need to change from extending `ArrayAdapter<String>` to just extending `BaseAdapter<MyDataObject>` (most of the methods in `BaseAdapter` are trivial to implement) since our data size, for example, would be determined by our list, and not the `ArrayAdapter`'s array.

I know that's kind of a fire hose, but let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you. So the first thing I need to figure out is how to change 'class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>' to 'class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MyDataObject>'. Also, can you write an example for correctly populating 'myList.get(index)'?

Comment: Thank you very much. Ultimately, I do want to use ArrayList and my data will be stored in a hashmap. Extending BaseAdapter is probably what I will have to do. You've laid out the roadmad with all the details for the initial steps and that's exactly what I needed. I appreciate you help.

Comment: I would if I could, but I need a reputation of 15. I will when I get there, perhaps you can upvote the question?

Comment: Returned the favor... 3 years later.

Answer (score 0):

Use a separator in string, like \t.

Or use an array of straing arrays.

Or use an array of `Pair<String, String>`.

Or use an array of custom objects.